# Mysql group by multiple combinations

Tags: mysql, group-by

I'm building a chat app in which two people will comunicate on enquiry, I want to fetch conversation between two users on enquiry, table structure is like below:

**Table: enquiries**

```
id, name, product, msg
```

**Table: replies**

```
id, enquiry_id(fk), from_user(fk), to_user(fk), msg

    +----+--------+-----------+---------+------+
    | id | enq_id | from_user | to_user | msg  |
    +----+--------+-----------+---------+------+
    | 1  | 1      | 1         | 2       | msg1 |
    +----+--------+-----------+---------+------+
    | 2  | 1      | 2         | 1       | msg2 |
    +----+--------+-----------+---------+------+
    | 3  | 1      | 1         | 2       | msg3 |
    +----+--------+-----------+---------+------+
    | 4  | 1      | 2         | 1       | msg4 |
    +----+--------+-----------+---------+------+
    | 5  | 1      | 1         | 3       | msg1 |
    +----+--------+-----------+---------+------+
    | 6  | 1      | 3         | 1       | msg2 |
    +----+--------+-----------+---------+------+
```

**What I'm doing**

I'm using using below query to fetch communication between two users on the basis of enquiries but it is giving two seperate records for same users & enquiry.

```
SELECT 
   r.enquiry_id, 
   r.from_user, 
   r.to_user, 
   count(1) replies_count 
FROM 
   `replies` r 
GROUP BY 
   r.enquiry_id, r.from_user, r.to_user
ORDER BY 
   r.id DESC
```

**This is the result of the above query**

```
    +--------+-----------+---------+-----+
    | enq_id | from_user | to_user | msg |
    +--------+-----------+---------+-----+
    | 1      | 1         | 2       | 2   |
    +--------+-----------+---------+-----+
    | 1      | 2         | 1       | 2   |
    +--------+-----------+---------+-----+
    | 1      | 1         | 3       | 1   |
    +--------+-----------+---------+-----+
    | 1      | 3         | 1       | 1   |
    +--------+-----------+---------+-----+
```

**And my expected result is like**

```
+--------+--------------+--------------+-----+
| enq_id | participant1 | participant2 | msg |
+--------+--------------+--------------+-----+
| 1      | 1            | 2            | 4   |
+--------+--------------+--------------+-----+
| 1      | 1            | 3            | 2   |
+--------+--------------+--------------+-----+
```

Comment: can be more than two distinct users in the conversation?

Comment: There will be single row for two users communicating on same enquiry, I've modified my question please check

Answer (score 1):

check it here if it is what you're asking for: http://rextester.com/TVOKS20933

```
select enquiry_id, from_user, to_user, count(1) msg 
from replies
group by enquiry_id, from_user, to_user
order by id;

+----+--------+-----------+---------+------+
| id | enq_id | from_user | to_user | msg  |
+----+--------+-----------+---------+------+
| 1  | 1      | 1         | 2       | msg1 |
+----+--------+-----------+---------+------+
| 2  | 1      | 2         | 1       | msg2 |
+----+--------+-----------+---------+------+
| 3  | 1      | 1         | 2       | msg3 |
+----+--------+-----------+---------+------+
| 4  | 1      | 2         | 1       | msg4 |
+----+--------+-----------+---------+------+
| 5  | 1      | 1         | 3       | msg1 |
+----+--------+-----------+---------+------+
| 6  | 1      | 3         | 1       | msg2 |
+----+--------+-----------+---------+------+    

+--------+-----------+---------+-----+
| enq_id | from_user | to_user | msg |
+--------+-----------+---------+-----+
| 1      | 1         | 2       | 2   |
+--------+-----------+---------+-----+
| 1      | 2         | 1       | 2   |
+--------+-----------+---------+-----+
| 1      | 1         | 3       | 1   |
+--------+-----------+---------+-----+
| 1      | 3         | 1       | 1   |
+--------+-----------+---------+-----+
```

Comment: This what is I'm doing right now, I want only one row for communication between two users. I have modified my question, please check

Answer (score 1):

A dialogue between two users can be grouped together as a single row if you ensure that the IDs always go in a specific order, for example, lower ID followed by higher ID. For just two elements, you can easily implement such an order using built-in functions [`LEAST`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_least) and [`GREATEST`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest). For instance, if you have rows:

```
from_user  to_user
---------  -------
1          2
2          1
1          2
```

and perform a query like this:

```
SELECT
  LEAST(from_user, to_user) AS participant1,
  GREATEST(from_user, to_user) AS participant2
FROM
  ...
```

the result will be:

```
participant1  participant2
------------  ------------
1             2
1             2
1             2
```

If you then use the expressions `LEAST(from_user, to_user)` and `GREATEST(from_user, to_user)` as grouping terms instead of simply `from_user, to_user`, your output will return a single row per each pair of users regardless of which one was `from_user` and which `to_user`.

Therefore, you can modify your query like this to achieve the desired output:

```
SELECT 
   r.enquiry_id, 
   LEAST(r.from_user, r.to_user) AS participant1, 
   GREATEST(r.from_user, r.to_user) AS participant2, 
   count(1) replies_count 
FROM 
   `replies` r 
GROUP BY 
   r.enquiry_id,
   LEAST(r.from_user, r.to_user),
   GREATEST(r.from_user, r.to_user)
ORDER BY 
   MAX(r.id) DESC
;
```

You can see that I also changed the `ORDER BY` from `r.id` to `MAX(r.id)`. While it is true that MySQL's non-strict mode permits you to select non-`GROUP BY` columns without aggregation, in practice this can be very misleading and cause unpredictable/inconsistent results where the selected column can have multiple values per group. I suggest you always wrap a non-`GROUP BY` column in an aggregate function when referencing it in `SELECT`, `HAVING` or `ORDER BY`.